# Add Change-Id to all commits

Tags: git, gerrit

I just installed Gerrit and I wanted to do a push to it, but I'm getting an error regarding `Change-Id`, but it appears to be in the commit it's complaining about.

```
$ git push gerrit HEAD:refs/publish/my-branch
Counting objects: 28, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 4.46 KiB, done.
Total 15 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (12/12)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
remote: ERROR: missing Change-Id in commit message footer
remote: Suggestion for commit message:
remote: Revert "Refactoring controllers"
remote: 
remote: This reverts commit dd1c5c86b12461f61326fd102a11d9e3cb51142e.
remote: 
remote: Change-Id: Iaacf80a9e4f56b58d0b648112c3eb2413988f00e
remote: 
remote: Hint: To automatically insert Change-Id, install the hook:
remote:   gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); scp -p -P 29418 user@ci:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/
remote: 
remote: 
To ssh://user@ci:29418/Project
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/publish/my-branch (missing Change-Id in commit message footer)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@ci:29418/Project'
```

I assume that this is because of previous commits that are without `Change-Id` because they were made prior to having the hook. How can I update all previous commits to add the `Change-Id`?

Comment: When importing a repository you would normally push to the master instead of pushing for review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gerrit - at the project settings page disable the option which requiring change-Id in commits temporarily. Then push the existing commits to Gerrit.

Comment: And then I can safely enable it again?

Comment: yes - after initiating the repo - then set back this option

Comment: Note that if someone modifies those commits and pushes back, they’ll be opened as new change; to prevent this, the change-id must be copied manually from Gerrit UI to the commit message.

Comment: Downvoting this, don't have permissions to change Gerrit, that's owned by another team and given bureaucracy, that's nearly impossible, plus others are constantly adding to the repo and this is a one-off thing.

Answer (score 3):

When you have hook, you can do rebase branch into itself in interactive mode

```
git checkout branchName
git rebase -i branchName
```

When you see interactive menu change keyword `pick` to `edit` near every commit that you have no change id. Then git will stop before "rebasing" every commit that marked as `edit`. On every stop you do `git commit --amend`,save changes(change id will be added automatically, if you have commit hook hrom gerrit, othrwise you need to add it manually), and then `git rebase --continue`. After that every commit in your branch will have change-id.
Rince and repeat for every branch you need.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45584050/1895378). You will need to use `git filter-branch --msg-filter` which will simulate the process of creating Change-IDs

Basically you want to make a new orphan branch (no prior history) and then rewrite all the commits to have Change-IDs.

The specific code sample you need is (verbatim from the answer [previously mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45584050/1895378))

```
#create an orphan branch "tmp" from "master".
git checkout --orphan tmp master
git commit -m 'new root'
#cherry-pick all the commits from an upstream kernel branch.
git cherry-pick <all-the-commits>
#rewrite the commit message of every commit on "tmp"
git filter-branch --msg-filter 'git log -1 --pretty=%B $GIT_COMMIT > msg.txt;~/commit-msg msg.txt;cat msg.txt'
#all the commits now have Change-Id
#cherry-pick all of them except the root to "master"
root=$(git log --pretty=%H --max-parents=0)
git checkout master
git cherry-pick $root..tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers to this question seem to be more complicated than needed. I'd like to suggest a refined and (hopefully) easier version of [HaoZeke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1895378/haozeke) answer.
First of all, I assume that the `Change-Id` adding message hook is already installed, like Gerrit instructs (`Hint: To automatically insert Change-Id, install the hook: ...`).

Then it should be enough to apply it on all commits in desired range with single git invocation:

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter '
    tmp=`mktemp` &&
    cat >$tmp &&
    $GIT_DIR/hooks/commit-msg $tmp &&
    cat $tmp &&
    rm -f $tmp' \
<YOUR_BASE_GIT_REV>..HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @Asprelis's answer, I found a one line command that rebases and ammends all commits in the specified range without the need to waste time in interactive mode:

```
git rebase -f HEAD~<num_of_commits> <branch> --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit"
```

Explanation:

According to the git documentation at:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

-f forces git rebase to "Individually replay all rebased commits instead of fast-forwarding over the unchanged ones. This ensures that the entire history of the rebased branch is composed of new commits"

and --exec "Append "exec " after each line creating a commit in the final history.  will be interpreted as one or more shell commands."

So in short, this command tells git rebase to rewrite and execute `git commit --amend --no-edit` on each commit you are rebasing.

If you installed the gerrit "commit-msg" hook, this will insert a Change ID into each commit.