# How to add a commit ID to a series of cherry picks?

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm trying to contribute to the LineageOS gerrit.

So essentially I cherry picked a range of commits from an upstream kernel branch...

Only now, none of the cherry picked commits have a Change-ID.
I know I can manually add one with a commit hook and:

```bsh
git commit --amend
```

However, there are 834 or so commits...
I'm also aware that I could run an interactive rebase to slightly ease my pain via:

```bsh
git rebase -i $FIRST_CP
# Change every commit from pick to edit
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

However this is almost just as bad as cherry picking every single commit all over again.

**Note:** I *do not* have admin access to the Gerrit server so I cannot temporarily remove the requirement of change IDs.

I'm at my wits end and this is really putting a damper on my contributions...
Hope someone has a better idea.

**Addenum:** I also tried merging the branch and hoping it would be accepted... No dice though.

Comment: `there are 834 or so commits` ... how many commits are you contributing here?  How did you end up in a situation where you need to rewrite so many commits?

Comment: Well, some context might be helpful.. I'm basically upstreaming the f2fs file system for my android device... To get it working. The problem is that their not all my commits (otherwise they'd have the change-id and I'd have no problem) All the cherry picks are required for the filesystem to work.. However none of them had a Change-ID

Comment: 834 is a big number. Maybe you could ask the project owner if these commits could be pushed without review. If the history doesn't matter, a squash-merge would be simple enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, LineageOS is... sort of too large of a project to allow stuff like that.. Too much red tape (it's also what allows it to remain as the most stable custom ROM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git filter-branch --msg-filter`.

Let's say we have the hook to generate Change-Id at `~/commit-msg`, and we are now on `master`.

```
#create an orphan branch "tmp" from "master".
git checkout --orphan tmp master
git commit -m 'new root'

#cherry-pick all the commits from an upstream kernel branch.
git cherry-pick <all-the-commits>

#rewrite the commit message of every commit on "tmp"
git filter-branch --msg-filter 'git log -1 --pretty=%B $GIT_COMMIT > msg.txt;~/commit-msg msg.txt;cat msg.txt'

#all the commits now have Change-Id
#cherry-pick all of them except the root to "master"
root=$(git log --pretty=%H --max-parents=0)
git checkout master
git cherry-pick $root..tmp
```

`msg.txt` is created in `.git-rewrite/` under the current repository, and `.git-rewrite/` is deleted automatically after the command is done. So let's just ignore it.

The msg-filter command simulates the process of generating Change-Id. I think it could be more elegant, but it works in my test.

Answer (score 0):

`-n, --no-commit` will let you cherry-pick one or more existing commits without any commit. After doing this, you can commit all those cherry-picked with one commit ID.

Comment: That's not very fair to the other contributers...In fact there are strict rules against that sort of stuff... It's even worse than squashing them.